# Creating Advanced Custom Search with Custom Post Types and Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have been trying to figure out a way to build an advanced custom search with in my WordPress build.

I have been looking at this thread for information: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields - but alas it doesn't seem to be helping and I have become stuck.

The spec for the form is:

The form needs to have 3 Select fields each with their own set of options.
The first field needs to filter the search results to a custom post type: either postTypeA or postTypeB.
The second select field needs to filter down by a custom attribute created in ACF (advanced custom fields) this field is level, level has 5 options: levelA, levelB, levelC, levelD, levelE
And finally it needs to filter by sector (This has been set via categories taxonomy), we also have 5 options here, sectorA, etc.
So the hope is that the result of the search will get extremely accurate results.

Example of my search form looks like this so far:

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" class="course-finder-form" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="who"><?php _e( 'I am a', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <select name="user" id="">
            <option value="learner"><?php _e( 'Learner', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="employer"><?php _e( 'Employer', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div> 

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="level"><?php _e( 'looking for', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <select name="level" id="">
            <option value="apprenticeship-standards"><?php _e( 'Apprenticeships', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="traineeships-and-internships"><?php _e( 'Traineeships and Internships', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="stand-alone-qualification"><?php _e( 'Stand Alone Qualification', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="sector"><?php _e( 'in', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <select name="sector" id="">
            <option value="property"><?php _e( 'Property', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="beauty"><?php _e( 'Beauty', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="business"><?php _e( 'Business', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="digital"><?php _e( 'Digital', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
            <option value="finance"><?php _e( 'Finance', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div> 

    <input type="submit" class="search-submit colourless-button" value="Find Course" />

</form>
```

PHP - added to functions.php for the search results page:

```
function wpse_load_custom_search_template() {
    if( isset($_REQUEST['search']) == 'advanced' ) {
        require('advanced-search-result.php');
        die();
    }
}
add_action('init','wpse_load_custom_search_template');
```

PHP - search results:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
// Get data from URL into variables
$_level = $_GET['level'] != '' ? $_GET['level'] : '';

// Start the Query
$course_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'learner_courses', // your CPT
        's'             =>  $_user, // looks into everything with the keyword from your 'user field'
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'level', // assumed your meta_key is 'level'
                                    'value'   => $_level,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE', // finds levels that matches 'level' from the select field
                                ),
                            )
    );
$courseSearchQuery = new WP_Query( $course_args );

// Open this line to Debug what's query WP has just run
 var_dump($courseSearchQuery->request);

// Show the results
if( $courseSearchQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while( $courseSearchQuery->have_posts() ) : $courseSearchQuery->the_post();
        the_title(); // Assumed your cars' names are stored as a CPT post title
    endwhile;
else :
    _e( 'Sorry, nothing matched your search criteria', 'textdomain' );
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Could someone please help how to filter searches via these elements, so first: post type, second: level (custom acf attribute), finally: sector (category).

I think I have put everything here needed to explain my dilemma, let me know if anything else is needed!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. We're here to help you with specific programming questions. Since I can't see any effort done by you to get your goal (I can't see any PHP code here, no SQL Querys, only a form) I think you won't get much help. You should try it by yourself and post what you've tried so far. If it doesn't work we'll help you. But nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: @Twinfriends - I am sorry I hadn't provided enough information, I am still pretty new to Stackoverflow but I am very thankful for the community.

I have now updated my above post to contain what I believe to be the relevant PHP. Is this better?